# Python - successive random calls to the same method

Tags: python, loops, sequence

On the following strip-down version of my program, I want to simulate an exchange where the user and the computer will act following a random sequence.

Here the variable  `row` contains the sequence order. A value of 0 means the program is waiting for a user input (method `val0`). A value of 1 means there should be an automatic process (method `val1`).

It seems to work at the beginning when alternating 0 and 1 but as soon as we are waiting for two successive automatic calls, it goes out of whack.

I tried using the `after` method but I can't see how and where to insert it.

A `while` loop might do the trick on this example but the end program is more complex, with sequence interruption, reevaluation of the sequence and so on. So I don't know if it would still apply then.

```
    from tkinter import *

class Application:  
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        self.master = master
        Label(master,text='press next').grid()
        Button(master,text='Next',command=self.val0).grid()
        self.index = IntVar()
        self.index.set(0)
        self.index.trace("w",self.nextTurn)

    def val0(self):
        print("User action")
        self.index.set(self.index.get() +1)

    def val1(self):
        print("Automatic action")
        self.index.set(self.index.get() +1)

    def nextTurn(self, *args):
        i = self.index.get()
        if i >= len(row):
            self.master.destroy()
            return
        if row[i] == 1:
            self.val1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    row = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
    root = Tk()
    win = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve your problem by calling the `nextTurn` directly in the automatic action function:

```
def val1(self):
    print("Automatic action")
    self.index.set(self.index.get() +1)
    self.nextTurn() # call nextTurn after this action
```

So if it was an automatic action, you step into the next row position, and call `nextTurn` again.

However this may become a problem if your `row` becomes too large because it uses recursion. In that case you will want another approach with the `while` you mentioned. For this second option you would only need to change `nextTurn`:

```
def nextTurn(self, *args):
    i = self.index.get()

    # while it is an automatic action and it has row values, keep calling val1
    while i < len(row) and row[i] == 1: 
        self.val1() # call automatic action
        i = self.index.get() #update the row position
    else:

        if i >= len(row):
            self.master.destroy()
            return
```

Comment: Thanks Isac, calling `nextTurn` inside `val1` is working here. It still skips a beat on the larger program but it is a definit improvement.

Comment: @user2748626 No problem. If the processing you have to do is too large, then you want to take a look at threading. The main idea is that you don't want to do any intensive computing in the UI thread, otherwise you lock the UI.